# nodejs - passport.use callback return dataValues and _previousDataValues instead of a normal object

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

I am using `passport.js` module for Authentication and Sequelize mysql for database management.

error occurs when authenticating user:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "message": "WHERE parameter \"id\" has invalid \"undefined\" value",
        "error": {}
    }
}
```

When authenticating the user, `console.log(jwtPayload)` in file `passport.js` shows below results.

```
{
  dataValues: {
    id: '06c19eb0-995f-45f4-81d7-26ec3b401234',
    email: 'CCCC@gmail.com',
    createdAt: '2021-05-14T01:51:31.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-05-14T01:51:31.000Z'
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: '06c19eb0-995f-45f4-81d7-26ec3b401234',
    email: 'CCCC@gmail.com',
    createdAt: '2021-05-14T01:51:31.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-05-14T01:51:31.000Z'
  },
  _changed: {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [ 'id', 'email', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt' ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false,
  iat: 1620961695
}
```

instead of

```
  {
    id: '06c19eb0-995f-45f4-81d7-26ec3b401234',
    email: 'CCCC@gmail.com',
    createdAt: '2021-05-14T01:51:31.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-05-14T01:51:31.000Z'
  }
```

passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
const passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
const JWTStrategy   = passportJWT.Strategy;
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var User = require('../models/Users')

module.exports = function(passport) {


passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey   : 'your_jwt_secret'
},
function (jwtPayload, done) {
  console.log(jwtPayload)
  return User.findOne({where: {id:jwtPayload.id}})
      .then(user => {
          return done(null, user);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          return done(err);
      });
}
));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize returns `dataValues` and `_previousDataValues` properties by design. You can pass the current values with a small modification.

```js
return User.findOne({where: {id:jwtPayload.id}})
      .then(user => {
          return done(null, user.dataValues);
      })
```